# Url not Shortening in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I I want to get a particular page url and shorten the url automatically, and show it to the user. After writing the below codes, it's not shortening properly.

Page url

```
127.0.0.1:8000/artlyf/1/topman
```

Page Url after shortening

```
127.0.0.1:8000/artlyf/1/topman/b
```

Models.py

```
_char_map = string.ascii_letters+string.digits

def index_to_char(sequence):
     return "".join([_char_map[x] for x in sequence])

class Mrts(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User)
     title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
     picture_1=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
     description=HTMLField(null=True,blank=True)
     slug=models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
     pub_date=models.DateTimeField()

     def __unicode__(self):
         return u'%s' %(self.title)

     def get_short_id(self):
          _id=self.id
           digits=[]
           while _id > 0:
              rem= _id % 62
              digits.append(rem)
              _id /=62
           digits.reverse()
          return index_to_char(digits)

     @staticmethod
     def decode_id(string):
        i=0
        for c in string:
            i=i*64+_char_map.index(c)
        return i

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.title)
         super(Mrts,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Views.py

## page url to be shortened

```
  def artdetail(request,mrts_id,slug):
      post=Mrts.objects.get(id=mrts_id,slug=slug)

      currentUrl = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_short_id())
      return render_to_response('postdetail.html',{'post':post, ' Mrts':Mrts,'currentUrl':currentUrl},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^artlyf/(?P<mrts_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\d\w]+)/$', 'artapp.views.artdetail', name='artdetail'),
```

Template

```
 {{currentUrl}}
```

How can it be shorten properly? Any good method in models that can be used to shorten urls ?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what do you expect this code to do. You haven't even provided urls.py entry for a shortened url.

Comment: sorry, does the shortened url needs an entry and should be placed in urls.py

Comment: Yes. I can't make out from your post how a shortened url is supposed to look like - is it just "/short-id" or "/artlyf/short-id" or maybe something completely different. Django can't either. You need a urls.py entry showing that, pointing to a view that is able to deal with a short id.

Comment: something like /short-id/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an entry in urls.py for the shortened url schema:

```
url(r'^(?P<short_id>\w+)/$', 'artapp.views.artshort', name='artshort'),
url(r'^artlyf/(?P<mrts_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\d\w]+)/$', 'artapp.views.artdetail', name='artdetail')
```

And methods on your model for getting both types of URL:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Mrts(models.Model):
    # ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('artdetail', args=[str(self.pk), self.slug])

    def get_short_url(self):
        return reverse('artshort', args=[self.get_short_id()])
```

A view for handling short url (this one just redirects to a full URL):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404

def artshort(request, short_id):
    id = Mrts.decode_id(short_id)
    object = get_object_or_404(Mrts, pk=id)
    return redirect(object)
```

You can display shortened URL in a template like this (where `post` is a `Mrts` object):

```
{{ post.get_short_url }}
```